# Call controller method from javascript that return regular view(not partial)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using devExpress controlls and I have code like this:

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.RowDblClick = "myJavascriptFunction";
```

and that mean that when I double click on control it invoke javascript function **myJavascriptFunction**.
I have controller like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /My/

    public ActionResult Index(string a,string b)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I want to call that controller method from my javascript.

I read [Calling ASP.NET MVC Action Methods from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952953/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript)

and [How to call a Controller method from javascript in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644658/how-to-call-a-controller-method-from-javascript-in-mvc3) and more...

but all suggest ajax call and I want to render the whole page to my controller...
someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean to just redirect them (no AJAX):

```
function myJavascriptFunction(){
  var a = 'foo', // to parameters of Index
      b = 'bar';
  window.location = '/My/Index'
      + '?a=' + encodeURIComponent(a)
      + '&b=' + encodeURIComponent(b);
}
```

Otherwise " I want to render the whole page to my controller. " is a little too vague. Please revise the question and be more specific and I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: and how to pass string a and string b?

Comment: @ilayzeidman: `'/My/Index?a=' + encodeURIComponent(a) + '&b=' + encodeURIComponent(b);`